# Blender 3.0 Selection Low Visibility

Tags: interface, edit-mode, theme

I noticed the visibility of selected vertices, edges, or faces in edit mode is much lower than what it was in older versions of Blender, especially on complex meshes, and more so on meshes with a lot of sharp edges.

Old: [image: old preview]

New: [image: new preview]

Is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: You can change the colours and thickness in sitting

Comment: It's already minimum thickness.  Higher thickness is worse.  The color doesn't change how the selection "shines through" or makes it appear on top of other edges.  The selection is obstructed by the edges around it, regardless of what color they are.

Comment: In the Overlays option menu, you can turn off the sharp edges. This way you can actually see what you have selected.

Comment: I know.  I need to see both at the same time.